# big negative number - postive giving postivie only

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have temp2 value -52340.0 and hslColor.Luminosity is 240.0

When `Dim temp1 As Double = (hslColor.Luminosity - temp2)`. It shoud give -ve number but I am getting always positive number.

results should nbe -52100, but I am getting +52100. How to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are doing:

```
Dim temp1 as Double = (240 - -52340.0)
```

You are subtracting a negative.

Answer (score 5):

240 - (-52340) = 52580

Do you remember what happens if you subtract a negative?

Answer (score 4):

> results should nbe -52100, but I am getting +52100.

That's a lie. You should be getting `52580`, not `52100`.

If you substitute the values in like this:

```
240 - -52340
```

You're subtracting a negative, so it's the same as adding a positive:

```
240 + 52340
```

Which equals `52580`.

---

> How to handle this?

To get the intended result of `-52100`, either use this if `temp2` is **always negative**:

```
Dim temp1 As Double = (hslColor.Luminosity + temp2)
```

or use this, if you need to subtract the [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of `temp2`, whether it can be negative or positive:

```
Dim temp1 As Double = (hslColor.Luminosity - Math.Abs(temp2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim temp1 As Double = (240 - -52340)
```

the answer will be 52580

```
Dim temp1 As Double = (240 - 52340)
```

the answer will be  -52100